# Hide a div when typing text into a field and show it again when the text is deleted

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the code below to hide a div when someone is start typing text inside a search field.

```
$('#search').keypress(function() {
$('#hello').hide();
$(this).focus();
});
```

My problem is that i don't know how can i display again the hidden div when the text into the search field is cleared. 
Can someone help or guide me?

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ka81e4qb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to make it work

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#hello').show();
    }else{
        $('#hello').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/56cwz3cv/) code

Comment: Yep :) It was very easy but couldn't figure it out !! Now it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can testing if field is empty (when **keyup** instead) :

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
if($(this).val() == ''){
  $('#hello').show();
}
else{
 $('#hello').hide();
 $(this).focus();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    var searchTermLength = searchTerm.length;
    if (searchTermLength == 0) {
        $('#hello').show()
    } else {
        $('#hello').hide()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    if ($("#search").val().length != 0) {
        $('#hello').hide();
    } else {
        $("#hello").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val().length ? $('#hello').hide() : $('#hello').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the change() function instead, which  is called only when the value of the field has been changed completely.

```
$('#search').change(function() {
if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('#hello').show();
}else{
    $('#hello').hide();
}
```

});

Comment: doesn't .change() require the input to have lost focus before it is fired. Meaning that it will not display the div until after the text input has been cleared and then the input loses focus. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes even I feel the same. The change event is fired only when the input loses it's focus.